# 100vh adding space at the bottom from anterior sibling

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I'm trying to make a very simple page, but I'm pulling my hair off trying to find a solution for the layout.

What I want to achieve is a simple header and below, some content ( I don't know the actual height of it, but won't probably cover the full height of the viewport) with a full background cover image that covers the remaining height.

I tried using 100vh on the container that's going to hold the content, but as you can see in the codepen: `http://codepen.io/renttless/pen/vGvzRj` , it creates a scrollbar apparently the size of the previous sibling, which will be the header.

Here's the code:

```
  <body>
  <div class="containerTest">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Who are we</li>
          <li>Our work</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="sectionTest">
     <div class="backgroundTest">
       <h1>I'm a full size h1</h1>
       <p>I'm some paragraph</p>


 </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
.sectionTest .backgroundTest{
    background-color:red;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: So the height of `.sectionTest` should be `<viewport height> - <header height>` or `100vh - <header height>`?

Comment: How do I calculate that? Is this expected behavior? or 100vh actually is the viewport of the entire screen?

Comment: That is expected. If your viewport is 1000px in height and your header is 100px then you will get a scrollbar as you're placing and element after the header that is equal to the height of the browser viewport. So you get `100px (header) + 1000px (content after header) = 1100px` and scrollbar appears since all your content has a greater height than the viewport's height. If your header has a set height you could try using `calc()` and subtract the header from the viewport height, `height: calc( 100vh - 100px );`

Comment: That's exactly right. What do I do when the content overpass the height of the container that has 100vh? since it doesn't expand.

Comment: I'm not following. What is the result that you want? If you're content takes up more space than your viewport you're going to either hide the overflow or provide a scrollbar. Where the scrollbar appears is up to you. The be on the viewport like you're getting now or you can have a scrollbar on the element containing the content.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain to do.  Maybe try using the **flexbox** approach. Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vfjdL1es/).

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Who are we</li>
          <li>Our work</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
       <h1>I'm a full size h1</h1>
       <p>I'm some paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  flex: 0 1 30px;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I only need the content below the header to have a background which should cover the remaining height. I did what you suggested, then added 100vh to backgroundTest a background-color, but same result as above.

Comment: @user2430929 I edited to try to better answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a background to your header and move the 100vh to the html element it will solve your problem

```css
    html{
        background-color:red;
        height:100vh;
    }
    header{
      background: white;
    }
    body, header ul{
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
  <body>
  <div class="containerTest">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Who are we</li>
          <li>Our work</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="sectionTest">
     <div class="backgroundTest">
       <h1>I'm a full size h1</h1>
       <p>I'm some paragraph</p>


 </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think the issue with this approach is that if he uses a background image then the top of the background image gets cropped. For solid colors or a background image with a pattern (at least some) this will work just fine.